# How to upload files using jQuery's ajax function with PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

Here's my nonworking attempt:

```
<script>
    function uploadImageSubmit() {

        var imageFile = $('.imageFile').val();

        $.ajax({

            url: 'ajax.php?request=upload-image&file='+imageFile,
            success: function(output) {
                 alert(output);                    
            }

        });

    }
</script>

<h2>Upload File</h2>

<form>
    <input type="file" class="imageFile" />
    <a onClick="uploadImageSubmit()">Upload</a>
</form>
```

The code on "ajax.php":

```
<?php

$action = $_GET['request'];

switch($action) {

    case 'upload-image':

        $imageFile =  $_GET['file'];

        $name = $_FILES[$imageFile] ['name'];
        $tmpLocation = $_FILES[$imageFile] ['tmp_name'];

            $upload = move_uploaded_file($tmpLocation, "files/$name");
            echo ($upload) ? $name.' uploaded successfully!' : 'File not uploaded.';

    end;

}

?>
```

I get the message file not uploaded. I think it's because even though strings can be passed via the url, File paths can't for some reason. But then again I have no idea why it's not working. Can someone figure out what's wrong please?

Comment: i think ajax got some problem with file upload http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, [HTML5 and the new File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3a.c2.a0Uploading_a_user-selected_file) does support uploading via XmlHttpRequest. It works beautifully in Firefox 4 and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

*XmlHttpRequest* has no support to upload files. you need to use some hidden iframe or a flash solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload file using plain JS/AJAX. A known trick is to post your file to a hidden iframe and update the iframe.