# How to upload a file with out page refresh in php?

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload files using jQuery's ajax function with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269660/how-to-upload-files-using-jquerys-ajax-function-with-php)

I am trying to upload a file in PHP with out page refresh,

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269660/how-to-upload-files-using-jquerys-ajax-function-with-php

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do so, actually. You can try [this plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). By default it uses a hidden iframe but if you do not need to support legacy browser, you can also make it use the AJAX FormData API (and thus use a real XHR).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by posting a form (which contains the file you want to upload) to a hidden iframe. That would cause the iframe to reaload instead the whole page, and since the iframe is hidden, nobody goning to notice. This is a common way to post files to the server side without reloading the whole page.

You may do something like this:

```
<form id="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="[posting-url-here]" target="targetIframe"></form>
<iframe id="targetIframe" name="upload_target" src="" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two many ajax uploader available on net that using Iframe to do so..

http://www.freshdesignweb.com/10example-ajax-upload-file-with-php.html

Try any one...